# Can I make pip install the 32 bit version of a package?

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, pip, debian-stretch

I am trying to run PSUtil on a Raspberry PI but keep getting `ELFCLASS64` errors.

I think this is because I am using the 64 bit version of PSUtil on a 32 bit operating system.

Looking at the PyPi page for PSUtil (https://pypi.org/project/psutil/), it states that 32 and 64 bit versions are available.

I am running pip install on a 64 bit OS to package everything together, but the final run time is 32 bit. When the code executes on the final run time (Raspberry PI running Stretch) I get `ELFCLASS64` errors when Python attempts to import PSUtil.

My build environment is a Docker container running on a 64 bit host OS. Another idea would be to try and make the docker container have the 32 bit version of Python/Pip on it. To that end I have tried to base the container on `python:2.7.15-stretch` but that also didn't work.

Would be grateful for any ideas on how to solve this problem.

Comment: which os are you using

Comment: Raspbian Stretch

Comment: did you try installing it from source

Comment: The psutil package? How do I do that?

Comment: download the package from [git](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil), unzip it, open the folder and run `python setup.py install`

Comment: Maybe **piwheels** can help... https://www.piwheels.org